# ERROR: Response[8] The requested amount of instances has exceeded GCE's default quota. GCP

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I know there are similar questions available but I have checked them all and after that, I am asking this question.

So while deploying a .Net application to GCP app engine I am getting following error:

> An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/insert_flex_deployment/flex_create_resources>2021-09-21T04:26:19.798Z105556.in.0: The requested amount of instances has exceeded GCE's default quota.

I am using **.Net 3.1** and **App engine Flexible** environment. Below are options I already tried:

1. Creating a new project and deploying the application there.
2. Creating separate services in the existing project.

Also below is the quota usage:
[image]

As you can see I am not over utilizing my quota limit and here is my App.yaml file:

```
runtime: aspnetcore
env: flex
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

Error when I deploy from **Google cloud SDK shell**:

```
Step #0: No .deps.json file found for the app
Finished Step #0
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/aspnetcorebuild@sha256:f5552a5efdaf278a3124ea10fd1c9636b09fc9f98f9e 620cbd71279797576b3f" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Cloud build failed. Check logs at 
https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/20606673-dc57-48b4-bd4d-a52206623dd3?project=383088687946 Failure status: UNKNOWN: Error 
Response: [2] Build failed; check build logs for details
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The quota you are displaying is for the region `us-central1`. What region are you using for App Engine? Do you mind showing the full error stack trace?

Comment: Do you have a billing account set up and attached to the project? Show the deploy command. Which region are you deploying in?

Comment: @Dondi I am using `us-central1` region only. @JohnHanley Also, I have a billing account setup and attached to the project.

Comment: Full error log: 

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [8] Flex operation projects/lucid-326512/regions/us-central1/operations/f46d7100-d546-4e81-abe6-2def5be921da error [RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED]: An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/insert_flex_deployment/flex_create_resources>2021-09-21T04:26:19.798Z105556.in.0: The requested amount of instances has exceeded GCE's default quota. Please see https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas for more information on GCE resources
Failed to deploy project LucidQBOIntegration to App Engine Flex.

Comment: There's an error message `RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED` so the region may not have enough resources as of now. There are few options. Wait for a while and retry, or create a new project and select a new region for App Engine.

Comment: @Dondi that is not the case because I created a separate project in a different region so there is nothing utilized.

Comment: Also, I don't see any errors in the build logs section.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a regional quota, a resource might not be available in a specific zone. For example, you might have quota to create VM instances in `region us-central1`, but you might not be able to create VM instances in the `zone us-central1-a` if the zone is depleted. In such cases, try creating the same resource in another zone, such as `us-central1-f`.

You can see more [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotashttps://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas).

Answer (score 0):

Your latest deploy is already exceeding the default quota for your app.

My suggestion to switch from `manual_scaling` to `automatic_scaling` and change your `instances: 1` to `min_num_instances: 1` and `max_num_instances: 5`.

Your code should look like this:

```
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 5
```

You can check other service scaling settings [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/reference/app-yaml#services) and working with quotas [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#monitoring_quota_metrics) for reference.